# Unable to put image url to Firestore database after uploading the image to firebase storage

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload some images to firestore storage and put the image URL to firebase database. The images are uploading successfully but the image URLs aren't being added to the database. The problem that I think might be causing this is that the image URL is being added to the Hashmap after uploading the image but the database upload process isn't waiting for the URL instead, adding all other HashMap keys to the database before the Upload task returns the URL. This way all other keys get added to the database but not the Image URLs. In the below code product id is being added successfully to the database, also if I leave any image unselected its url alse gets added as empty to the database which is working fine but if I select an image to upload, The hashmap to database upload finishes even before getting the uploaded image URL.

```
public class AddProductDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String productId;
    EditText productIdEditText;
    ImageView addProductImage3;

    Button addProductSubmit;

    final int IMAGE3_REQUEST = 30;

    Uri image3LocationPath;

    StorageReference objectStorageReference;
    FirebaseFirestore objectFireBaseFireStore;

    Map<String, String> objectMap = new HashMap<>();
    StorageReference img3Store;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_product_data);

        brandNameEditText =(EditText) 
        addProductImage3 = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.add_product_image3);


        objectStorageReference = 
        FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("images");
        objectFireBaseFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


        addProductImage3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent objectIntent = new Intent();
                objectIntent.setType("image/*");

                objectIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(objectIntent, IMAGE3_REQUEST);
            }
        });


        addProductSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                productId = productIdEditText.getText().toString();

                if(image3LocationPath != null)
                {
                    final String image3Name = productId + "_image3." + getExtension(image3LocationPath);
                    img3Store = objectStorageReference.child(image3Name);
                    UploadTask imageUploadTask = img3Store.putFile(image3LocationPath);
                    imageUploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                            if(!task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(AddProductDataActivity.this, "Task Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            return img3Store.getDownloadUrl();
                        }
                    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                               if(task.isSuccessful())
                               {
                                   String image_3_url = task.getResult().toString();
                                   objectMap.put("image3_url",image_3_url);
                               }
                               else
                               {
                               Toast.makeText(AddProductDataActivity.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       }
                   });
               }
               else
               {
                   objectMap.put("image3_url","");
               }


               objectFireBaseFireStore.collection("images").document(productId).set(objectMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                       Toast.makeText(AddProductDataActivity.this, "Product Added Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                       Toast.makeText(AddProductDataActivity.this, "Error in Adding Product. Please Try Again.\n"+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               });
           }
       }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode){

            case 30:

            try
            {
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
                {
                    image3LocationPath = data.getData();
                    Bitmap objectBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), image3LocationPath);

                    addProductImage3.setImageBitmap(objectBitmap);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

            default:
            break;

        }

        private String getExtension(Uri uri){
            try
            {
                ContentResolver objectContentResolver = getContentResolver();
                MimeTypeMap objectMimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                return objectMimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(objectContentResolver.getType(uri));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(AddProductDataActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After posting question where you gone?

Comment: Got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code

```
objectFireBaseFireStore.collection("images").document(productId).set(objectMap)
```

executes before

```
objectMap.put("image3_url",image_3_url)
```

Which means when you are setting your url, your `objectMap` does not have the key `image3_url`

Try to set values to database inside `onComplete()` or use different workaround to set only the url.

Comment: But why is it executing the Firestore part before executing the image's part?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add your HashMap to Database Reference of Firebase.

This is reference from my current project code.

```
private void uploadVideo() {
        StorageReference mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        final StorageReference riversRef = mStorageRef.child(Constants.STORAGE_PATH + "/" + mFinalUploadUri.getLastPathSegment());
        riversRef.putFile(mFinalUploadUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException());
                }
                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                return riversRef.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    FirebaseFirestore database = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

                    String mSelectedCategory = binding.categorySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    DocumentReference newDocumentReference = database.collection(PENDING_PATH).document();

                    VideoModel videoModel = new VideoModel();
                    videoModel.setDocumentId(newDocumentReference.getId());
                    videoModel.setTitle(mTitle);
                    videoModel.setCategory(mSelectedCategory);
                    //videoModel.setTime(FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

                    videoModel.setUrl(downloadUri != null ? downloadUri.toString() : null);

                    newDocumentReference.set(videoModel).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            binding.button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            binding.videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            selectedUri = null;
                            Toast.makeText(AdminVideoUploadActivity.this, R.string.uploaded_successfully, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(AdminVideoUploadActivity.this, R.string.failed_to_upload, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Now you can check code and find where you have done mistake. Just add lines of code of inserting in database.

Thank you.